# How to get an old version of a deleted forum post from google chrome cache history?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, webpage

I'm not sure whether "cache history" is the right word
What I'm trying to do is this:
I was viewing a forum page on chrome, and I refreshed the page
It turns out the author had deleted the page and so a refresh brought out the page has been deleted message
However just a second ago the page was still there in the chrome window
Is it possible to get back the version of the page before it got deleted, through chrome's temporary files on my computer?
Preferably I want to do this without installing anything extra
Chrome version is

```
Version 64.0.3282.186 (Official Build) (32-bit)
```

Comment: No, because when you refresh the page Chrome updates the cached data for that page in it's storage. Only way would be if you didn't visit that page again in the browser after the change/deletion. Mainstream browsers don't keep a history of old versions of the same page.

Comment: @acejavelin so that means if I press the refresh button, I should close the browser immediately before the page refreshes, in order to have any chance of being able to view the older version of the deleted page?

Comment: If you hit refresh, it's probably already too late...